# Having trouble with tcp mode on HAProxy running on OPNsense

Tags: haproxy, freebsd

I'm trying to setup HAProxy to do simple tcp passthrough to different backends based on SNI. However, I have serious issues on my clients if I do so:

- Firefox: PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR
- Brave/Chrome/Safari: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED (works after several reloads but the error shows again intermittently)

If I contact the backends directly, bypassing HAProxy, I have no such issues. So something in HAProxy is not configured right but I fail to see what it is.

Technical Details:

- HA-Proxy version 2.0.14
- Running on OPNsense 20.1.x, 20.7.x (FreeBSD 11.2, 12.1)
- In a virtual machine on ESXi 6.7U3

My config looks like this:

```
global
    # NOTE: Could be a security issue, but required for some feature.
    uid                         80
    gid                         80
    chroot                      /var/haproxy
    daemon
    stats                       socket /var/run/haproxy.socket group proxy mode 775 level admin
    nbproc                      1
    nbthread                    1
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param   1024
    spread-checks               0
    tune.chksize                16384
    tune.bufsize                16384
    tune.lua.maxmem             0
    log /var/run/log local0 info

defaults
    log     global
    option redispatch -1
    timeout client 30s
    timeout connect 30s
    timeout server 30s
    retries 3

# Frontend: https_passthrough (https tcp mode main ip)
frontend https_passthrough
    bind x.x.x.x:443 name x.x.x.x:443
    mode tcp
    # tuning options
    timeout client 30s

    # logging options
    # ACL: service_sni
    acl acl_5f34555b7fae76.76760871 req.ssl_sni -i service.example.com

    # ACTION: service_https_passthrough
    use_backend service_https_passthrough if acl_5f34555b7fae76.76760871
    # WARNING: pass through options below this line
    tcp-request inspect-delay 10s

# Backend: service_https_passthrough ()
backend service_https_passthrough
    # health checking is DISABLED
    mode tcp
    balance source
    # stickiness
    stick-table type ip size 50k expire 30m
    stick on src
    # tuning options
    timeout connect 30s
    timeout server 30s
    server service_https_passthrough 10.0.1.105:443
```

If the connection fails I find entries like

```
https_passthrough https_passthrough/<NOSRV> -1/-1/0 0 SC 1/1/0/0/0 0/0
```

in the logs. But as I said, the backend servers are up and running 24/7 and work fine all day from internal LAN (also routing/firewall/VLANs involved here) so I doubt it is a firewall issue.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like adding these two lines to the frontend config fixed the issue for me:

```
tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
```

Derrived from a [HAProxy blog post](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/enhanced-ssl-load-balancing-with-server-name-indication-sni-tls-extension/).